# React and Search engine crawler without SSR

Tags: html, reactjs, google-search

I have a React project with multiple pages, and I'm not utilizing any Server-Side Rendering (SSR) framework. However, I want to assist search engine crawlers in indexing my site effectively.

In my scenario, I'm interested in providing only one page to the search engines—the homepage component. (The data derived from my server is irrelevant for search engine indexing.)

Currently im using the html head tag to help the crawler indexing (feel free to suggest more)

```
<head>
  // i added those i found relevant to the search engine
  <meta name="description" content="some content for search engine about my site">
  <meta name="keywords" content="some keywords for search engine">
  <title>my site</title>
</head>
```

In addition I'm considering two approaches, but I'm uncertain about their effectiveness and which one is preferable:

1. Link Rel in index.html: Adding a link element within the  section of the index.html file, pointing to a static HTML file (homepage.static.html) that contains the relevant content for the homepage:

```
<head>
  <!-- Other head elements -->
  <!-- Link to the static HTML file containing homepage content -->
  <link rel="preload" href="/path/to/homepage.static.html" as="document">
</head>
```

2. Temporary div Element: Adding a temporary div element alongside the main content container () in the index.html file, and removing it using a useEffect hook in app.tsx:
   //index.html body element

```
<body>
  <div id="homepage_static">
    <!-- Static content relevant for search engines -->
  </div>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

app.tsx

```
var elementToRemove = document.getElementById("homepage_static");

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    elementToRemove?.remove();
  }, []);

return <Something/>
```

Both approaches seem similar to me, but I'm uncertain if they're equally effective for search engine indexing.

Additionally, I understand that maintaining changes in the homepage component within the static homepage.static.html file could be challenging (so I would like to hear opinions about that also).

Comment: Why use a static home page at all?  These days Googlebot executes Javascript and indexes client side rendered content.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i wasnt sure about it . so in that case there is no need in the static homepage. The flow of the googleboot is to wait until the javascript loaded and then it read the html?

Comment: It waits for a limited time (a few seconds) for the page to render and then indexes content from the document object model (DOM) rather than the HTML source code.  There are a bunch limitations if you are relying on search engines to index JavaScript rendered content.  See my answer to [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140250/do-search-engines-perform-js-rendering-while-crawling) for details.